# Get bucket item count in Couchbase

Tags: .net, couchbase

I'm just getting started experimenting with Couchbase (v1.8) using the .NET client.  I can't figure out how to get a basic count of items I've stored in the default bucket.

My storage code is pretty simple:

```
var client = new CouchbaseClient();
var session = new Session { SessionId = "session_1234" };
client.Store(StoreMode.Add, sessionId, session);
```

But now I just want to get a count of all the sessions I've stored in my couchbase bucket.  I've looked at the .NET API docs and can't seem to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the client doesn't support getting an item count from buckets.  I've done some work recently to start a basic bucket API.  I've created a ticket for adding the item count - http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/NCBC-92.

If you're interested in where that count would come from, it's available over the HTTP API - 
`http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/buckets/default` <- bucket name is at the end of the path

If you're new to Couchbase Server, I'd suggest starting out with Couchbase Server 2.0 Developer Preview 4 - http://www.couchbase.com/download.  You could then use views to count session documents.

More information about 2.0 is found at http://www.couchbase.com/develop/net/next.

-- John

Comment: That's great, thanks for that, 2.0 sounds promising, if I can add views as needed that sounds like the best approach.